# How do I sign a VSTO deployment?

Tags: clickonce, vsto, code-signing, authenticode

Client purchased a code-signing certificate, and it came with a `.pvk` file and a `.spc` file. I am familiar with the `.pvk` file, but Visual Studio doesn't recognize the `.spc` file.

When I try to load the `.spc` file as the ClickOnce Certificate, a message box says "The selected file does not contain a private key. You must choose a certificate that contains a private key."

Did the client buy the wrong thing, or am I not in the right spot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google is your friend.

http://jcsearch.com/blogs/PCTechSupport/312

Comment: This tutorial doesn't fill you in 100%, a few more googles will find the full answer, but for simplicity's sake, here it is: there are two other flags you need to call when exporting to the pfx file: pvkimprt -import –pfx c:\codesign\mycert.spc
c:\codesign\mycert.pvk